# Can anyone tell how we implement nesting Exception in php?

Tags: php, exception

I am new to PHPand learning it from php.net. I have seen a note on the reference link page (http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.extending.php) which says that:

> Versions of PHP 5, prior to PHP 5.3.0 do not support nesting of exceptions.

But my question is what is nesting exception and how we implement nesting Exception in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception nesting (or linking, as it's apparently also called in the comments below the page) is having the option to pass a previous Exception to a newly created one, so you can wrap a low-level exception in a higher level one.

See the constructor for Exception:

```
public function __construct($message = null, $code = 0, Exception $previous = null);
```

Specifically the part where you're allowed to pass a $previous Exception is what they mean with nesting; the constructor in PHP < 5.3.0 do not have that argument.

(You can still pass it, because this is PHP, but it won't do anything)